# Changelog of a question thread

Tags: feature-request, notifications

When a post in a thread has been modified, it appears in the recent questions area, but unless the question is closely followed, one cannot notice take note of what the changes are. This applies to both our own question (answer modifications aren't notified unless answerer comments to questioner) and questions that piques our interest, namely the ones we have favorited or provided an answer to.

Forum threads have an option to see "new posts since last visit", we need something like that here as well, or at least allow the user access to what the changes have been made in the thread.

**EDIT**

Just post revisions is not enough, as I explained in my comment to Rebecca's answer. Large community wikis will have posts edited and answers added, and post revision logs do not help in that matter. I stand by my request and ask for a thread-level revision log.

Comment: try `/posts/12345/timeline` but it's in perpetual beta as we can't figure out how to make it usable by human beings. Good luck!

Comment: @Jeff, indeed it's a bit confusing. Anywhere we can post inputs for improvement and hopefully breakout of the vicious cycle of perpetual beta?

Comment: Ah, and this would be an acceptable answer.

Comment: search meta for "timeline"

Answer (score 4):

When a post has been edited, this information will be shown with a link that takes you to a revisions page.  The revision will show you a diff of what has changed, as shown [on this revision page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/96502/revisions).

[image: edited post]

To keep track of posts you want to look at later, you can either use your browser's bookmarking, or you can favorite the answer.  Your favorites can be accessed by hovering over your name at the top of the page, which will show you the number of changes, and you can also click through to your list of favorites.

[image: favoriting]

Comment: But of course, why didn't I try clicking that!

Comment: However, that's not enough. We need indicators what post has been updated, specially for large community wikis. It's difficult to figure out if a new answer has been posted or an older one updated. So I'd still like to suggest a thread-level revision log.